# Pass a token with "::" as argument to C/C++ macro

Tags: c++, namespaces, macros, c-preprocessor

Suppose I have two structs with the same member variables but different "prefixes". One is in a namespace and the other is prefixed with a certain token.

I want to write a macro to do the same operation on these structs which accepts the differing prefix as an input. I tried this:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A__foo_
{
  int bar;
} typedef A__foo;

namespace B {
  struct foo {
    int bar;
  };
}

#define GET_BAR(Prefix)\
  { \
    Prefix ## foo my_foo;\
    printf("Bar is: %d", my_foo.bar);\
  }

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  GET_BAR(A__);
  GET_BAR(B::);
}
```

I get this compiler error:

> macros_example.cpp:22:7: error: pasting formed '::foo', an invalid preprocessing token
>         GET_BAR(B::);

Is there a way to rewrite this macro in an elegant way to accept the two inputs and concatenate them with "foo"? I've tried pre-processing B:: by concatenating "B" and the double colons. I've also tried changing `Prefix ## foo` to simply `Prefix foo` but then calling `GET_BAR(A__)` causes a compile error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to appreciate the solution I came up with out of context, but here it is:

```
#define CONCATENATE_A(X) A__ ## X
#define CONCATENATE_B(X) B:: X

#define GET_BAR(CONCATENATE)\
  { \
    CONCATENATE(foo) my_foo;\
    printf("Bar is: %d", my_foo.bar);\
  }

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  GET_BAR(CONCATENATE_A);
  GET_BAR(CONCATENATE_B);
}
```

basically, pass a concatenation function rather than the tokens themselves.

Answer (score 1):

`::foo` is not a preprocessing token. `::` and `foo` are tokens. The token-pasting operator is for forming a new token based on other tokens.

You will have to use a different macro for these two use cases.

Comment: > You will have to use a different macro for these two use cases.

Different? Like what?